# How to get a variable keyboard input in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

In my game that I came up with, I have to press the key corresponding to the letter falling. However, I do not know of a function, class, statement, etc. that can help me with this. So Python chooses a random letter from a list and I want to know if the player has pressed that key corresponding to it. If the player has, it will spawn another letter. Here is my code:

```py
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *

# Set the height and width of the screen
window_width = 700
window_height = 500
size = [window_width, window_height]
game_win = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# Creating colors
white = (225, 225, 225)
black = (0, 0, 0)
gray = (100, 100, 100)

# Setting a font
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("consolas", 25)
large_font = pygame.font.SysFont("consolas", 80)

# Setting a window name
pygame.display.set_caption("Letters Game")


# Creating a messaging function
def message(sentence, color, x, y, font_type, display):
    sentence = font_type.render(sentence, True, color)
    display.blit(sentence, [x, y])


# Main function
def mainLoop():
    # Creating a letter list
    letters = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    random_letter = random.choice(letters)

    # Initializing PyGame
    pygame.init()

    # variable to keep a loop going
    done = False

    y = 12
    y_moved = 0

    random_x = random.choice(list(range(50, 550)))

    # Starting a loop
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            y_moved = 7

        y += y_moved
        game_win.fill(black)

        message("Type the letter before it touches the line", white, 10, 10, font, game_win)

        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, white, [0, 450, 700, 5])

        message(random_letter, white, random_x, y, large_font, game_win)

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        clock.tick(25)
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the `KEYDOWN` event and evaluate the `.unicode` attribute of the event (see [event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)). Note, since your characters are capital letters, you have to get the lower case character form `random_letter`:

```py
def mainLoop():
    # [...]

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            y_moved = 7

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.unicode == random_letter.lower():
                    print("correct")

    # [...]
```

Comment: wait it does it for every single key, so if the letter "I" is coming down and type something else, it still would say correct

Comment: No, I have tried it, it works for every single letter.

Comment: Ok maybe i have made a mistake. Edit=[Yea i have made a mistake]